# Can you find the next number in the following series? 14, 1, 13, 0, 23, 21,?

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

Replace the question mark with the next number:

> 14, 1, 13, 0, 23, 21, ?

Comment: Every time I see numbers in the range of [0--25] or [1-26]ish I think of the alphabet.  And once I do, I have a hard time scrubbing that from me addled mind...

Comment: [Not on OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=14%2C+1%2C+13%2C+0%2C+23%2C+21)

Answer (score 3):

One answer could be

> 44

As,

> Around zero(the central number, around which the remaining 6 numbers are dispersed), the spreading -out differences form a sequence of an arithmetic progression with a common difference of 10. So the ? should be 44

For,

> (23 - 13), (21 - 1), ( ? - 14) forming A.P. and thereby giving ? = 44.

Comment: Why would the setter choose (13,23) instead of say (17,27)?

Comment: @JonMark Perry - well, that may optionally be checked with the problem setter. :D

Comment: Or anything else..? Obviously ..good question